# Firebase Google Auth Error

Tags: java, android, firebase

Hello I have been working on an project of an android app so i used firebase android google authentication but when i launch app and login it works fine and after closing app and relaunching it app stucks on white screen please help im posting my file below

googleutil.java

```
public class GoogleUtil {

    public static boolean getBooleanPreference(Context context, String key, boolean defaultValue) {

        boolean value = defaultValue;

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        if (preferences != null) {

            value = preferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);

        }

        return value;

    }

    public static boolean setBooleanPreference(Context context, String key, boolean value) {

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        if (preferences != null) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

            editor.putBoolean(key, value);

            return editor.commit();

        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

google.java

```
public class Google {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 10;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private FragmentActivity context;

    private OnInfoLoginGoogleCallback mGoogleCallback;

    public Google(FragmentActivity context, OnInfoLoginGoogleCallback mGoogleCallback) {

        this.context = context;

        this.mGoogleCallback = mGoogleCallback;

        getConfigDefaultLogin();

    }

    private void getConfigDefaultLogin() {

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)

                .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))

                // TODO: 25-05-2017 Check With JSON default_web_client_id !!! Important

                .requestEmail()

                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)

                .enableAutoManage(context /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                        mGoogleCallback.connectionFailedApiClient(connectionResult);

                    }

                }).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build();

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

            if (result.isSuccess()) {

                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();

                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

            } else {

                mGoogleCallback.loginFailed();

            }

        }

    }

    public void signIn() {

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);

        context.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount acct) {

        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(context, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

            @Override

            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                    mGoogleCallback.loginFailed();

                } else {

                    mGoogleCallback.getInfoLoginGoogle(acct);

                }

            }

        });

    }

    public interface OnInfoLoginGoogleCallback {

        void getInfoLoginGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account);

        void connectionFailedApiClient(ConnectionResult connectionResult);

        void loginFailed();

    }

}
```

and finally implement all these in main activiity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Google.OnInfoLoginGoogleCallback {

    private static final String USER_ROOT = "User";

    private static final String KEY_LOGIN = "Key_Login";

    private Google mGoogleSign;

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Window window = getWindow();

        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView server_load = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secure_key);

        server_load.setText("Server Secure " + Math.random() + " Key");

        firstShow();

        if (GoogleUtil.getBooleanPreference(this, KEY_LOGIN, false)) {

            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

            finish();

        }

        initViews();

    }

    private void firstShow() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("app", MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isFirst", true)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OnboardingActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            editor.putBoolean("isFirst", false);

            editor.apply();

        }

    }

    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        mGoogleSign.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    @Override

    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.sign_in_trigger:

                signInGoogle();

                break;

        }

    }

    @Override

    public void getInfoLoginGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

        sendUserFirebase();

    }

    @Override

    public void connectionFailedApiClient(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        addProgressBar(false);

        toast("Error Play Services COD" + connectionResult);

    }

    @Override

    public void loginFailed() {

        addProgressBar(false);

        toast("Login Failed");

    }

    private void initViews() {

        mGoogleSign = new Google(this, this);

        Button mBtnGoogleplus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_trigger);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_progress_bar);

        mBtnGoogleplus.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void signInGoogle() {

        mGoogleSign.signIn();

        addProgressBar(true);

    }

    private void toast(String mensage) {

        Toast.makeText(this, mensage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    private void addProgressBar(boolean flag) {

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(flag ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    }

    private void sendUserFirebase() {

        DatabaseReference referenceUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(USER_ROOT);

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (firebaseUser != null) {

            User user = new User();

            user.setName(firebaseUser.getDisplayName());

            user.setEmail(firebaseUser.getEmail());

            user.setPhotoUrl(firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() == null ? "default_uri" : firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString());

            user.setuId(firebaseUser.getUid());

            referenceUser.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                @Override

                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        GoogleUtil.setBooleanPreference(MainActivity.this, KEY_LOGIN, true);

                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FeedActivity.class));

                        finish();

                    } else {

                        toast("Login Failed Send User, try again.");

                    }

                    addProgressBar(false);

                }

            });

        }

    }

}
```

and also i used User.java to send user email to database

User.java

```
public class User {

    private String Name;

    private String Email;

    private String UID;

    private String PhotoURL;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String name, String email, String uId, String photoUrl) {

        this.Name = name;

        this.Email = email;

        this.UID = uId;

        this.PhotoURL = photoUrl;

    }

    public String getName() {

        return Name;

    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.Name = name;

    }

    public String getEmail() {

        return Email;

    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {

        this.Email = email;

    }

    public String getuId() {

        return UID;

    }

    public void setuId(String uId) {

        this.UID = uId;

    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {

        return PhotoURL;

    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {

        this.PhotoURL = photoUrl;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So much code.
As I understood, you need some silent log in in background.
Here You go:
OptionalPendingResult example:

```
// LogIN pending result
mGoogleApiClientPendingResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mGoogleApiClientPendingResult.isDone()) {
        // There's immediate result available.
        // Handle you result here
        handleSignInResult(mGoogleApiClientPendingResult.get());
    } else {
        // There's no immediate result ready, displays some progress indicator and waits for the
        // async callback.
        mGoogleApiClientPendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult result) {
                // Handle you result here
                handleSignInResult(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

Main Activity example:

```
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 28;
private static final String RC_SIGN_IN_TAG = "GoogleSignIn";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> mGoogleApiClientPendingResult;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// Google Log In
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                // Change this for Your needs
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER), new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_FILE), new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        //
                    }
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .build();
        // LogIN pending result
        mGoogleApiClientPendingResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mGoogleApiClientPendingResult.isDone()) {
            // There's immediate result available.
            // Handle you result here
            handleSignInResult(mGoogleApiClientPendingResult.get());
        } else {
            // There's no immediate result ready, displays some progress indicator and waits for the
            // async callback.
            mGoogleApiClientPendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult result) {
                    // Handle you result here
                    handleSignInResult(result);
                }
            });
        }
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }

    }

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(RC_SIGN_IN_TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            if (acct != null) {
                // Do your things here
                nameTextView.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
                emailTextView.setText(acct.getEmail());
                // You can gat methods here - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount
            }
        }
    }
```